# Is there a name for starting a chapter with a quote?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I am writing an article for school, and am trying to find the term used to describe a chapter which starts with a quote; my supervisor has said that there is a term for it, but he *cannot remember what it is!*.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the term is _cliche_

Comment: This is a question about identifying a term, and not about writing. I'm going to send this to English Language and Usage. Have you attempted to find this word yourself? If so, please edit the question to indicate this. English may close the question there otherwise.

Comment: @NeilFein Heh ... from Writers to ELU, and now an [unintentional duplicate](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/3789/17) on Literature. This query sure gets around!

Answer (score 35):

Starting a chapter with a quote is known as an **Epigraph**

So sayeth Wikipedia:

> In literature, an epigraph is a phrase, quotation, or poem that is set at the beginning of a document or component.

And Google Define:

> **epigraph**
>   *ˈɛpɪɡrɑːf/*
>   noun
>
> 1. an inscription on a building, statue, or coin.
> 2. a short quotation or saying at the beginning of a book or chapter, intended to suggest its theme.

Comment: That's the name for the quote, not the chapter.  But I think it's what he wants, even though not what he asked for.  AFAIK, there is no special name for such a chapter, unless it's "epigraphical chapter," which is stupid.

Comment: @dmm, H'mm I see what you mean actually. "What's the name for /Starting/ a chaper..." sounds like he's looking for the name of the process. I would guess the process is known as "epigraphy", but that is a real word meaning the study of incriptions. Meh, I've drawn a blank and Google refuses to yield an answer, so haha I'm gonna agree with you that there's no special name :-)

Comment: It's quite possible that the OP or the teacher is confused about precisely what he wants a word for, or just didn't express it properly in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You're all not reading the definition carefully enough.  Epigraph means "a short quotation or saying at the beginning of a book OR CHAPTER."

The answer to his question is:  "epigraph."

Oh, I see, I think he misspoke.  He doesn't mean the name of the chapter; that's silly.  He means the name of the quotation.